# Remove � character from classic asp page

Tags: html, asp-classic

I created a classic asp page and in that page I am reading from an RSS feed. In the feed description it shows this statement. Please provide me any solution for this.

I want to remove  this character � from page   Responsorial Psalm�Ps 19:8, 10, 12-13, 14

Comment: Look into character encoding. The strange character is most likely a result of mixed character encoding :)

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Morten Jensen - still not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may edited the asp page in MS word or some other editor which converts UTF 8 chars to this kind ANSI. Please open in note pad and **save as UTF-8** format by selecting from dropdown